# Кастомизация actionBar - текст по центру + кнопка "home"

Tags: android

Мне нужно реализовать следующий actionBar:
[image]

Для этого хотел провести такую кастомизацию:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_menu);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);   
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); 
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    textView.setText("title");

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail_view, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Вот custom_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" 
 />
```

И вот menu_detail_view.xml - пустой

В итоге получается, что текст по середине, а кнопки "home" нет. Как быть? Уже и не знаю что править...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить в `LinearLayout` значение `layout_width="wrap_content"`. А то весь лэйаут занимает всё видимое место, а кнопка есть, но за пределами экрана.

Comment: о, черт, это гениально!!!!)

Comment: и работу с `ActionBar` перенести в `onCreate`

Comment: @monomi большая разница?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` предназначен для работы с меню и инициализации `action bar` там не место

Comment: @monomi при работе с фрагментами изменять ActionBar будет лучше именно в onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: @Deadkenny пруф?!